# Как "изменить питание земли" на STM32f103C8Tx?

Tags: stm32

Всем привет! Такой вопрос: у меня есть дисплей. Некий 5641AH10 (не играет роли). Дело в том, что я спаял ножки к пинам A - 9 для одной земли (в зависимости от минуса - на дисплее изменяется разная палочка для разных цифр) там находится 4 места для цифры: 0.0.0.0. К примеру, если минус подключён к 3-й ножке, а плюс к 2-й, то поставится 1.0.0.0, если минус на 4-й ножке - 0.1.0.0, т.е это как курсор. Как я могу изменить его? Не зря же на плате 3 GND стоят

---

Вопрос заранее: возникла идея. Можно ли подключить минус к пину общего назначения, и подавать через него питание? К примеру, минус сделать на B1. Тем самым, можно 4 курсора сделать на PB, и управлять. Или не будет принимать?

Comment: Без даташита на дисплей сложно сказать.

Comment: @MaximTimakov Вот тоже мучаюсь. Всё подключил, впихнул все курсоры в один GND. Выглядит красиво, но как что бы разные цифры были))

Comment: В принципе можно настроить выводы `MCU` на `open-drain`. НО: у stm32 есть ограничения по току, поэтому скорее всего потребуется поставить внешние ключи.

Comment: @MaximTimakov это вы про способ с использованием свободных пинов как GND?

Comment: То есть вы хотите просто в процессе выполнения программы подключать и отключать вывод микроконтроллера от земли? В любом режиме порта при установке логического нуля порт напрямую подключается к земле.

Comment: Вроде бы вот даташит http://www.xlitx.com/datasheet/5641AH.pdf

Comment: пример использования https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/SAnwandter1/programming-4-digit-7-segment-led-display-2d33f8

Comment: Только при подключении учтите, что у `stm32f103` максимальный ток намного меньше, чем у `ATMega`(`Arduino`): можно спалить чип.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь. Никак не мог найти даташит @MaximTimakov